# Check python header on macro text processor install script

Tags: makefile, macros, mingw, autotools, mingw-w64

The header files are typically installed with Python. On Unix, these are located in the directories $prefix/include/pythonversion/ and $exec_prefix/include/pythonversion/, where $prefix and $exec_prefix are defined by the corresponding parameters to Python's configure script and version is sys.version. On Windows, the headers are installed in $prefix/include, where $prefix is the installation directory specified to the installer. 
So I have this macro

[Macro](https://pastebin.com/20wNUs74)

the problem is on this piece of code

```
if test "$PYTHON_PLATFORM" != "win32"; then
   py_versiondir="/python${PYTHON_VERSION}"
else
   py_versiondir=
fi
```

MinGW (on windows) for example can have versioned header python folder so the script don't work.

How I can fix it?

Comment: What's "it"? Whether there are versioned Python folders (a link would be handy, I've never heard of those)? What the versioned Python folders *are?* How to get them? Something else entirely?

Comment: @l0b0 on MinGW the python header file are on versioned folder eg python2 or python3

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't bring me any closer to understanding the question. Python doesn't have header files.

Comment: @l0b0 https://docs.python.org/2.0/api/includes.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing for Autoconf, you should consider adding the [`AX_PYTHON`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_python.html#ax_python) macro from [the Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) to your package, and using it.  (Be mindful of licensing requirements if you do this.)

Or if, for whatever reason, you don't want to use `AX_PYTHON` then at least have a look at it to see that it works by getting Python to tell it the answer.  Here's the heart of it:

```
 ax_python_header=`$ax_python_bin -c "from distutils.sysconfig import *; print(get_config_var('CONFINCLUDEPY'))"`
```

(`$ax_python_bin` is previously set to the path to a Python executable.)